# Custom Post Type Category On Admin

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created custom post type called 'video' and added category support. The problem is when i go to category of custom post type, it shows normal post's categories as well.

I wanna seperate them How can i fix this?

---

**My custom-post-type code:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_video' );

function register_cpt_video() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Videolar', 'video' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Video', 'video' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Yeni Video Ekle', 'video' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Yeni Video Ekle', 'video' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Video Düzenle', 'video' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'Yeni Video', 'video' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'Video Görüntüle', 'video' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Video Arama', 'video' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Herhangi bir video bulunamadı', 'video' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Herhangi bir video bulunmadı', 'video' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Ebeveyn Video', 'video' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Videolar', 'video' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'description' => 'Video Galeri içeriklerinizi buradan giriniz.',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-video-alt2',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'video', $args );
}
```

Comment: Create custom taxonomy for the custom post type

Answer (score 2):

You've added the following line to arguments: `'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),`. It will register the same categories and tags to `video` post type which you're using with default posts.

First things first: remove line `'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),`

In order to have a new "exclusive" taxonomy only for `video` post type, you'll need to register a new taxonomy. This should go to same `.php` file where you're registering your new post type if it's  exclusive to only `video` post type. This is not mandatory but it's better for future maintenance.

---

I've added few arguments that I usually specify. See all the possible args **[here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)**. **Read the whole document to get what you actually need.** Some of these arguments alter the behaviour a lot.

```
// Video categories
add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_video_category', 0 );

function register_taxonomy_video_category() {

    $labels = array(
        // See list of labels in docs I linked above (bold and blue "here")     
    );


    $args = array(  

        // Custom labels? Remove them all to get "default"
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Does these have child-parent relationships?
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        // Translatable pretty slugs?
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => __( 'video-category', 'video' ) ),
        // Generate a default UI for managing this taxonomy?
        'show_ui'             => true,
        // Allow automatic creation of taxonomy columns on associated post-types table?
        'show_admin_column'   => true,
        // Show in quick edit panel?
        'show_in_quick_edit'  => false
        )  
    );

    // "video-category" is the name of the taxonomy
    // "video" is the post type you want it to use with
    register_taxonomy( 'video-category', 'video', $args );
}
```

---